# AMD transpiling at runtime

Tags: javascript, dojo, requirejs, amd, babeljs

I'm working on a Dojo project that would like to start using Babel (aka 6to5) to transpile ES6/ES7 features to ES5. (I think the same question would apply to anyone using Dojo and CoffeeScript or TypeScript.)

Everything works fine if we run the Babel transpiler before opening pages on our website, but that's really tedious for development. We'd like to configure Dojo's AMD loader to automatically transpile JS files as they're loaded.

Is this possible? It seems like it might be possible if we define/declare an [AMD plugin](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/loader/amd.html#plugins), but then we'd have to put a prefix on literally all of our dependencies, e.g. `require["babel!myfile.js", "babel!anotherfile.js"]` which seems unnecessary when we know that all of our JS should be transpiled.

Is there a way to tell Dojo/requirejs to automatically transpile everything?

Comment: Might be easier to just write a little watcher program on your server that any time you edit a source file in a particular directory, it automatically transpiles it for you.